# Displaying a sequence of images in Linux

Tags: linux, images, animation, octave

I'm generating a sequence of images saved as .PNG files on disk, labelled say plot001.png, plot002.png, plot003.png.    These are actually saved plots from Octave, a scientific data manipulation/plotting tool.

There are about 50-200 of these images.

I want to animate them on screen so I can see each frame displayed sequentially with my own specified pause between each frame (typically 200ms).  I also want to be able to manually single step forwards and backwards in the sequence with a simple keypress.

**I am not trying to create a video!** I could use ffmpeg or something similar, but the resulting video would be compressed, hard to control frame by frame, and only 2 seconds long.

Several Windows image display tools like irfanview have a feature for this.. it allows you to play a slideshow with definable pause between the frames, and you can also just arrow left and right to manually control. This is perfect.

Is there a image preview tool for Linux that would give me this easy sequence viewing method?  I'm running Ubuntu 9.10 if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Gwenview](http://gwenview.sourceforge.net/), which is available in Ubuntu 9.10, support that.

You can start a slideshow of any directory/images.  Its default pause between images is 5 seconds, but you can configure it as you want.  You can also step forward by pressing `space` or backward by pressing `backspace`.

Comment: This works pretty well. 
Surprisingly the slideshow timing is NOT configurable, but as a ad-hoc solution I can change my key repeat speed and hold down the space bar. Thanks!

Comment: @BobBanana When the slideshow is running, and you move your mouse at the top of the screen, a "toolbar" should appear.  Click on "Configure full-screen mode" (the wrench icon).  In the popup menu, the first thing should be a slider to adjust the timing.  At least, in Gwenview 2.3.2

Answer (score 10):

From imagemagick:

```
animate -delay 10 *.jpg
```

You can also use mplayer:

```
mplayer 'mf://*.jpg' -mf fps=10
```